# How to add/Insert Extension in magento 2.0?

Tags: magento, zend-framework, magento2, magento-2.0

I tried to add the external magento-2 extension but I can't add it because I can't find magento-connect in admin side. I think the admin panel doesn't have magento-connect. Do you have any idea about this to share, or a good tutorial that could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Magento 2 extension is an easy task .. you just need to extract your extension zip file and place the folder inside your Magento 2 app/code directory so that the structure should be like app/code/namespace/module-name

then you have to run some commands for registering your Magento 2 extension

open terminal inside your Magento 2 directory, parallel to the app directory

run these commands-

1. giving read write permission to your magento 2 directory

   sudo chmod -R 777 /path of Magento 2 folder  such as /opt/lampp/htdocs/Training/Magento_2.0

if you are using linux operating system then you have to run this command . for windows it is not necessary.

2. for registering your extension

   `/opt/lampp/bin/php bin/magento module:enable Namespace_Modulename`
   `/opt/lampp/bin/php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
3. for compiling your extension code

   `/opt/lampp/bin/php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

now flush your cache , delete cache folder from your Magento 2 `var` directory.

Answer (score 2):

This full feature is coming soon, but you can test it with sample data.

1. You need to install magento **without sample data**, via composer create project as specified [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/integrator_install.html).
2. Login to admin and navigate to `System` and look for `Web Setup Wizard` under tools.
3. Navigate to `Magento Marketplace` and enter your authentication keys for magento.com as specified [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/connect-auth.html).
4. If you navigate back to component manager and click `sync`(this step may take a while), "purchases" made in the marketplace will *eventually* show up here. ***This is still WIP***.
5. For now, you can test it with sample data modules. Under `New Purchases` it should show number of new modules(for now 20 for the number of sample-data modules). If you click `install` below that, you should be able to see a list of sample-data modules that can be installed.
6. Select the modules you want to install and click the `install` button on the upper left side of the grid. Or install one component at a time.
7. There will be a dependency check(which takes a while), based on composer that checks newly required components. This step requires cron to be setup. [Instructions here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/bk-compman-upgrade-guide.html)
8. Next, you can optionally create a backup, and then finally install component, which is done via the crons setup in previous step and composer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly download the extension you want to install.
Then unzip it. 
Open Filezilla and copy or upload app folder to your Magento 2 public_html folder. 
Once files are uploaded. 
Run the following SSH commands using Putty.

- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento setup:di:compile
- php bin/magento cache:clean
- php bin/magento cache:flush

You can then go in to the Magento 2 backend and Refresh Cache.
That is how to add or install an extension.