# Magento Extension Installation - No Magento Connect in Admin

Tags: magento, magento2

I have one very big problem.
I have installed Magento 2 Community Edition.

I am trying to install Magento Extension from Using magento-connect, but there is one problem. 
When I login to Magento Admin, and go to Tools I really do not see anything where I can paste my magento-connect URL.

Can someone help me please?

I have installed Magento 2 with Sample data.

Best regards,

Comment: As per my knowledge till now magento 2 do not support , magento connect.

Comment: @Muk Thank you for the fast answer. How can I install extension?

Comment: Can you name the extension which you want to install.

Comment: @Muk Yes, sure [link](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/14604/s/dixeno-findologic-6870/)

Comment: It is supported only for Magento 1.X series.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34200901/how-to-add-insert-extension-in-magento-2-0/

Answer (score 0):

Magento-2.0 does not support magento connect.

Because of syntax mismatch in magento-1.x and magento-2.x, this extenison https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/14604/s/dixeno-findologic-6870/ will not work in magento 2.0

Hope you understood well.