# How can I install an extension in Magento 2.x via Magento Connect Manager?

Tags: magento, content-management-system, magento2, magento-2.0

I have installed Magento core, I've registered developer's "Secure Key", I've entered these Public and Private keys into "Component Manager" of my Magento instance, I've clicked the "Sync" button.

I click "Install now" on the extension's page. But I have still 0 packages to install: [image]

How can I install an extension?

Comment: This is currently a "Contact the developer" thing and playing with Composer. The process is known as "Early Adopter" syndrome, or "Living on the Bleeding Edge".

Comment: @jonasasx This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34200901/how-to-add-insert-extension-in-magento-2-0/34213438, please see response there

Answer (score 1):

There is no Connect for Magento 2 yet.

Comment: But, how can I install an extension?

Comment: You should ask the extension's developer for it. I have such documentation for my extensions: https://mage2.pro/c/meta/first-steps Also, I have a generic instruction how to install an extension from a Git repository: https://mage2.pro/t/25

Comment: The amazing thing is that you've never needed Connect to install extensions. You could either use the command line version to download for manual installation or buy the module direct from the developer who often recommended manual installation as most successful method of getting things running. At this point it's a "contact the developer" type thing. Git 'n composer...